# Applovin and cocos2d IOS integration

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, applovin

HI i'm trying to develop a function that uses APPLOVIN to show adds. i don't see any errors messages an nothing, The game starts normally but no add is shown
I imported the library 
I think i'm doing all the correct steps:

1)Importing all libraries into the project
  2)setting the KEY that APPLOVIN provides
  3) set the -OgjC configuration key
  4)Do all imports into the delegate class
  5) load library

```
[ALSdk initializeSdk];
```

and

```
[ALInterstitialAd showOver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

I did all the steps posted here: https://www.applovin.com/integration#iosIntegration
     Is it any step that i need to perform in order to show an add?
   I looked into some other posts and they use an banner object, but don't know how to integrate in        COCOS2d. can someone provide some guidance on this please?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applovin Integration Steps :

1. Initialize

   ```
   -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
   {
        [ALSdk initializeSdk];
   }
   ```
2. Show Ads :

   ```
    -(void)showAplovinAds
    {
         [ALInterstitialAd showOver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]]; 
    }
   ```
3. Add SDK Key in info.plist
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your your time and help.. i did all this, but no add is shown.. Also in the applovin page for manage the app i see mi app name, That means that the SDKKEY is in the correct place

Comment: even I don't see any ads :) Applovin not show ads for India and some other country + in simulator ads are not displayed.

Comment: OH.. that must be what happens then, will search for a solution for this.. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe is a way to simulate that the emulator is running in some other country, some configuration or something, will try something like that..

Comment: You can enable "Test Mode" in the dashboard. You'll get some sample ads for testing even if nothing else is serving.